# A pagination technique using PHP, Javascript, MySql and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i hope to be clear. **I am a junior programmer**.

I'm working on a **personal project**, where I use wordpress to make some things easier for me, but I don't use wordpress core to read my posts (at least not at all).

**I'm developing a plugin**, which has the main function of book management register.
The plugin has a custom table in the database, where it contains all the books objects and creates a table in the admin view where it shows all the books. The plugin also allows me to edit them by clicking on them. So far so good. I hope I have given an idea of the project.
Now, since in a situation of large numbers of books, **like 60,000 books**, I need to create a pagination system.

And I've never programmed a paging system from scratch.

My ideas were two:

1. Create a single request to the server, save the database locally and work with javascript, moving between the indexes.
2. Or, to know the total number of elements, create an index offset and use this range of indexes by generating new requests to the sever perhaps with AJAX.

But I'm not convinced.

Is there a technique to create pagination of large data ?
Could you share with me your ideas or how you would have approached all this?

Thank you all.

Comment: Generally the second option is better, you don't have the overhead of local downloading all the data and index it.
Using a raw query to retrieve data, I usually write a basic query, then first I wrap it with a count() query to get the number of rows, then I add the sorting and limiting statements to the basic query to retrieve the subset of the data relating to the searched page.

Comment: @Pippo Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your feedback

Comment: For large datasets, it's always better to fetch the data in chunks, and not all of it at the same time.

Comment: When there are a large number of database records potentially to return in your sql using `limit x,y` type approach of selecting `pages` of data can be memory/database intensive when into high page numbers. It is often, afaik, considered preferable to use a range of ID values ( if these are contiguous ) such as `select ... where id between X and Y`

Comment: @Professor Abronsius, Thanks, but if the ids are not contiguous, but let's assume that it is a search by title, then the books can be with non-continuous ids, in which case how should we act? what is a possible solution?

Comment: I solved the problem of the ids, or rather there never was, it was just my mistake of thought.